# Can't instantiate type even though class and constructor exist

Tags: java, class, servlets, constructor, instantiation

So I'm actually writing this particular code to deal with Servlet and Handler.

```
ContentHandler handler = new ContentHandler();
contents = handler.translateToContent(doc);
```

I face the error of can't instantiate type. however on my ContentHandler class, I have already have an empty constructor. I don't quite understand where is the error at. I'm following an example and it works but it doesn't work on this. Please help and I appreciate it.

```
public ContentHandler() {
}

public ArrayList<ContentBean> translateToContent(Document doc) {
    NodeList contentNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("dc");
    ArrayList<ContentBean> contentList = new ArrayList<ContentBean>();

    for (int i = 0; i < contentNode.getLength(); i++) {
        Node n = contentNode.item(i);
        NodeList contentElements = n.getChildNodes();
```

Many thanks!

Regards.

Comment: How about if you just removed the empty constructor entirely?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: It is solved. It is because of org.xml.sax.ContentHandler. Misinterpreted. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your code is suffering from wrong class import. Check, you may be mixing the import with `org.xml.sax.ContentHandler`, which is an interface and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Hi Juned Ahsan,

Ahhh perfect. THANK YOU SO MUCH! Fixed the error and yes it is caused by the org.xml.sax.ContentHandler.

This is my first time doing this and thank you for your help. Much appreciated.